# X-files: Fluke -- could it communicate or show any evidence of intelligence or human behavior?

Tags: the-x-files

As I recall, they simply released this thing which clearly was not human or at the very least an atypical and dangerous-looking human. If it could speak and there was no evidence against it, I could understand -- they would have just treated the creature like a human who had some profound disability or illness but if it never spoke, what was the rationale for releasing it?

Comment: I think you may be remembering incorrectly what happened in that episode

Comment: @Revenant: I am pretty sure they release, or at least discuss releasing, it -- please tell me what I am misremembering. Perhaps it escapes, but they were sort of treating it as human. I don't know if this was a joke about political correctness or what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It escaped on the way to a facility where it was going to be psychologically profiled while the episode does not explicitly show it one can presume that after capturing the creature it showed at least some level of cognition which raised the question of is it an animal to be put down or is it a person to be institutionalized.

Skinner and Mulder had a discussion on the nature of the creature but there was no discussing about just releasing it.